# How to change a text based on click without change it back except when the page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, html

i'm really new in javascript and php.. i have a case..

```html
<label><a href="#" class="pull-right" style="margin-top: -5px;" id="moreupload">
                                                    <!--<?php
                                                        $count = substr_count($html,'<div class="col-md-12 row" style="margin-top:10px;">'); //where $html holds your piece of HTML.
                                                        if ($count>=0){
                                                            echo "Add Design";}
                                                        else{
                                                            echo "Upload Design";
                                                        }
                                                        ?>-->
                                                    Upload Design</a></label>
```

so i want to change the "upload design" text based on user click..so if user click => 1 it change  to "add design" without refreshing the page.. any idea how? sorry for my bad English

Comment: What is the one? Is it another button?

Comment: Use client-side JavaScript to process the click. Find the <a> element in the DOM by its ID. Then you can set the innerHTML property on the element, iirc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a click event to `moreupload` by getting it by `getElementById('moreupload')`. And after that you can change it's `innerHTML` like following:

```js
document.getElementById('moreupload').addEventListener('click', function() {
    // Change the text
    this.innerHTML = 'Add Design'
});
```

```html
<label>
   <a href="#" class="pull-right" style="margin-top: -5px;" id="moreupload">
    <!--<?php
        $count = substr_count($html,'<div class="col-md-12 row" style="margin-top:10px;">'); //where $html holds your piece of HTML.
        if ($count>=0){
            echo "Add Design";}
        else{
            echo "Upload Design";
        }
        ?>
    -->
    Upload Design
   </a>
</label>
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

To change button text you don't need PHP. It purely front-end. But what with button functionality. Does Upload and Add buttons do different backend call? If so, it is more efficient to hide and show needed buttons. Javascript is what you need.

Html:

```
<a href="#" class="pull-right" style="margin-top: -5px;" id="moreupload">Upload Design</a>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#moreupload").on("click",function(){
 $(this).text("Add Design");
});
```

PS: not sure if you should wrap  into , look into docs about  usage. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp